# Looping through array to get distance between objects

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So im trying to loop through an array of 'enemies' which are sprites, and get their X, Y, Width, Height values (i think my actual collision code is right) for a collision response but having trouble doing that. I know why im having a problem (the element[i] is just taking away from its own value )I just cant figure out how to get past it. Ive tried doing nested for loops but have not had success. Here is the initial patch of code:

```
       for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
        {
            if (enemies[i].x < enemies[i].x + enemies[i].width &&
                enemies[i].x + enemies[i].width > enemies[i].x &&
                enemies[i].y < enemies[i].y + enemies.height &&
                enemies.height + enemies.y > enemies.y)

                {
                    console.log("Colliding");
                }
        }
```

Thanks to any help in advance!

Comment: please add `enemies` and a wanted result.

Comment: Yea sorry that was a mistake its supposed to be enemies[i], must have ctrlZ too far.

Comment: you have an array (probably) called `enemies`, then inside loop you try to access `element` and also `elementp`, please, take some time to read your code and edit the question with a [mcve] to help people that is trying to help you

Comment: Yea just updated the question.

Comment: your description still showing thing about `element[i]`. Please, also show us an example of the `enemies` array with the objects inside

Comment: Sorry but, this is a horrible and non-sense code. `enemies` can't have `height` property because it's not an object. Plus,`enemies[i].x < enemies[i].x + enemies[i].width` and `enemies[i].x + enemies[i].width > enemies[i].x` has no difference between each other.

Comment: What collisions are you trying to check? Between each of the enemies (each vs each) or between enemy vs hero?